# Get attachment extension with MailKit

Tags: attachment, mailkit

I want to get extension for each attachment for each message from inbox. How can I do this? My destination: if only one attachment from inbox has a *jpg extenstion, rest of messages can skip and user will receive a info in MessageBox. With this code `attachment` is always null:

```
IList<IMessageSummary> allMailList = client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);
                foreach (IMessageSummary mail in allMailList)
                    foreach (var attachment in mail.Attachments)
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(attachment.FileName + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure in your Fetch() request.